# Power Query functions : best way to import another data format in same table?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-datasource

I have a data set that I import in PowerBI using PowerQuery and calling a function to transform my binary into a table.

My original data set consist in daily Excel files that I transform slightly.

Recently I've stumbled across a legacy database of the same data but arranged differently and I'd like to import it in the same table (there is a full year of data in a single file).

I was wondering what is the cleanest way to conditionally call my function:

- if daily Excel, call function A to transform it and import in my table
- if yearly database, call function B to transform it and import in my table.

I don't see the option to do that, I only see conditional columns but not conditional function calls in my PowerBI desktop.

Thanks !

Comment: How about loading the different formats separately and appending the results together once they are in the desired end format?

Comment: Not sure how to that ! How can I append a full table with another ? Thanks !

Comment: In the Query Editor, you can use the Append Queries button. Note that you can also disable load for the two separate results and only load the combined table after appending.

Comment: oh my god,  i've been using powerbi for years and had no idea you could do that ! it's very elegant thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you invoke your function, but you can manipulate transformation by modifying M code in Advanced Editor. Create two steps as independent flow in my example #"Added Custom" and #"Added Customv2";

here example, try this code:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMlTSUXJUitWJVjKCs4yBLCcwywTOMgWynMEsMzjLHKIjFgA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [DayOfWeek = _t, Duty = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"DayOfWeek", Int64.Type}, {"Duty", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each "ALLShift"),
    #"Added Customv2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each "MorningShift"),
    #"EndStep" = if Date.Month(DateTime.LocalNow()) = 9 then #"Added Custom" else #"Added Customv2"
in
    #"EndStep"
```

Check EndStep

```
#"EndStep" = if Date.Month(DateTime.LocalNow()) = 9 then #"Added Custom" else #"Added Customv2"
```

As you see, depending on current month I show in output #"Added Customv2" or #"Added Custom". You can in this same way change your source based on some if conditions.

Comment: Thanks but it doesnt seem to work, i tried your method and the following, and it doesn't seem to interpret the end result as a table.
   #"Colonnes renommées" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Premiers caractères extraits",{{"Name", "DateCode"}}),
    #"EndStep" = 
        if Text.EndsWith([DateCode], "2021") then 
        Table.AddColumn(#"Colonnes renommées", "fct_import_archives_crjo", each fct_import_archives_crjo([Content])) 
        else Table.AddColumn(#"Colonnes renommées", "fct_importCRJO_Q1C", each fct_importCRJO_Q1C([Content]))
in
    #"EndStep"

Comment: what am i missing ?

Comment: neither does it work if i follow strictly what you wrote :     #"Colonnes renommées" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Premiers caractères extraits",{{"Name", "DateCode"}}),
    #"col1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Colonnes renommées", "fct_import_archives_crjo", each fct_import_archives_crjo([Content])),
    #"col2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Colonnes renommées", "fct_importCRJO_Q1C", each fct_importCRJO_Q1C([Content])),
    #"EndStep" = if [DateCode]= "01092021" then #"col1" else #"col2"

Comment: it indicates (in french : Expression.Error : Nous avons détecté un identificateur inconnu. Avez-vous utilisé la syntaxe raccourcie [field] pour un _[field] en dehors d'une expression « each » ? )

Comment: Wait I think I’ve got it to work ! I’ll post my code as it is slightly different from your answers. Thanks anyways, it definitely got me going !